# List Payments returns max of 100

Tags: square-connect

Using the Square Connect API and listing payments.  The results always stop at 100 records. The documentation says I should see a link: with a URL because the results are being paginated.  The only thing I see in the header response is

[Link] => ;rel='next'

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

John

Comment: The pagination link should appear surrounded by angle brackets just before the semicolon in the header you describe above. As a first suggestion, is it possible you are viewing the header response in an environment that is escaping out the portion surrounded by angle brackets?

Comment: No, there are lots of angle brackets in the response.  Here's the full response.

[Status] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[Strict-Transport-Security] => max-age=2592000
[X-FRAME-OPTIONS] => DENY
[X-XSS-Protection] => 1; mode=block
[X-Content-Type-Options] => nosniff
[X-Request-Id] => uzGuwGvgR9OjrTVluuA1
[Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => *
[Access-Control-Expose-Headers] => Link
[Link] => ;rel='next'
[Content-Type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
[Content-Length] => 221861
[ETag] => "-1387126947"
[X-Response-Time] => 1411ms
[Date] => Wed, 06 Aug 2014 02:42:00 GMT
[Transfer-Encoding] => chunked